# Adjust model Materialize CSS to the content

Tags: html, css, materialize

Does anyone know how to adjust Modal to it's content without the extra padding ?

please find below the demo link jsfiddle

Click

```
<div class="center-modal">
    <div id="modal1" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="card"></div>
            ........
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/b0Lrm2th/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have full with by applying this CSS:

```
.modal.open {
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.modal .modal-content {
  padding: 0;
}

.card {
  .....
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mamounothman/fgdu763v/15/)